# Retain Sass syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 2 when embedding Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, erb

I am embedding Ruby in a few Sass files—I have files named, for example, `file.css.scss.erb`.  When I add the .erb extension to these files, I lose the Sass syntax highlighting. Does anyone know how to retain the Sass formatting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open your `.sass.erb` file, and go to :

```
View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as... > Sass
```

Comment: This config is stored on `..../Package/User/Sass.sublime-settings`, so you can save it later and avoid some syntaxs plugins.